# Creating an email account for a user when the name already exists

Tags: email

Looking for some suggestions/best practices.

I have an employee, let's say "John Smith" with an email address of "jsmith@domain.com". His son just came on board as an employee, and his son's name is also "John Smith". Is it common practice to have "jsmithjr@domain.com" or is there some other practice that I am not thinking of?

---

Update - I agree with tchalvak - I asked it it would be ok to use his middle initial and last name, which he agreed to.

mh, I'm surprised there isn't a best practice for this - there seems to be a best practice for everything computer related. heh.

Comment: and your programming question is......

Comment: and your programming question is......

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault...sounds like a Mail Server Maintanence question to me.

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault...sounds like a Mail Server Maintanence question to me.

Comment: It's just a naming convention, so as long as it adheres to the rules of SMTP addresses it's not the kind of thing that there would be a best practice for.  RFC2821 is the bible for SMTP and doesn't specify any standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask the employee if there is another shortening that he would prefer.  I would hate to be tagged with an email address like jsmithjr@whatever.com without being asked, as I happen to value my individuality.

Answer (score 5):

There is no common practice.  Some people add an alphanumeric suffix, some differentiate by middle initial, some let the person choose.  So pick the naming convention that *you* feel meets *your* requirements best, and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the employee if there is another shortening that he would prefer.  I would hate to be tagged with an email address like jsmithjr@whatever.com without being asked, as I happen to value my individuality.

Answer (score 1):

It's far more common practice to name him `jsmith1` or have some such numbering scheme.

Comment: For non-programmers, this should be jsmith2, shouldn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

At my office we use JSmith@email.com as the 1st John Smith, for the second John Smith, we give them JoSmith@email.com.  Seems to be working out fairly well for us.  In the rare instances where we have used those up, we'll add a period between first and last name/initial.  John.Smith@email.com or j.smith@email.com